# React TreeSelect inject custom filtering logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

I have been trying to alter logic in TreeSelect React component.

So, what I am trying to do is to search by value, but with trimmed spaces, for example if we have entries:

> dog
> cat
> fish

when entering           `dog` it should return me `dog` entry, simply - ignore spaces at the beginning, while still keeping them in UI.

I tried

```
const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState('')
...
<TreeSelect
    ...otherProps,
    filter
    filterValue={filterValue}
    onFilterValueChange={(e) => setFilterValue(e?.value?.trimStart())}
/>
```

but unfortunately this affects how component work and while typing spaces at the beginning, it also trims it in displayed value, giving wrong user experience.

**QUESTION**

Is there simple way I can somehow override this filtering?

Maybe somehow by changing equality comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to work around it. Simply make the TreeSelect controlled component and supply your own input in `panelHeaderTemplate` property of `TreeSelect`.

This way you can inject bit of extra logic in filtering:

```
import { useCallback, useState, ChangeEvent } from 'react'
...
const [filterValueProxyState, setFilterValueProxyState] = useState('')
const handleFilterValueChange = useCallback(
  (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    // here we trim filter proxy value, to filter by trimmed string in TreeSelect list
    setFilterValueProxyState(event.target.value.trimStart())
  },
  [props.onProxyFilterValueChange]
)

<TreeSelect
  panelHeaderTemplate={<textarea value={filterValue} onChange={handleFilterValueChange}/>}
  filterValue={filterValueProxyState}
  {...restProps}/>
```

This is merely pseudo code, as most probably `textarea` is not best choice here, but I just wanted to describe how it could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the equality comparison logic by passing a custom function to the `filterOption`.

so first create the compare function and pass it in `filterOption`.
if that not work for you try `filterTreeNode={trimStartAndCompare}`

```js
const trimStartAndCompare = (searchValue, optionValue) => {
  return optionValue.trimStart() === searchValue.trimStart();
};

const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState('');

...

<TreeSelect
  ...otherProps,
  filter
  filterValue={filterValue}
  filterOption={trimStartAndCompare} // add this part
  onFilterValueChange={(e) => setFilterValue(e.value)}
/>
```

Comment: I guess it's not correct overload accpetable in TreeSelect, i get error trying to do this

Comment: And i don't see any documentation for it.

Comment: I guess it was supported in older React versions.

Comment: try using filterTreeNode like so filterTreeNode={trimStartAndCompare}

Comment: Also, does not exist

Comment: when i look at the documentation its shows . what version you have ?